# Experience with third party Web.UI controls like Component Art

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Has anyone used Component Arts Web.UI controls?

They look like a great set of tools but is it worth the $998 they charge?

Answer (score 2):

The controls are decent. I have been using, the grid, tree view, splitter and dialog for a year now. The biggest problem is their lack of documentation; however, their support team is preety good at resolving issues and making up their lack of documentation.

I have also used their callback control; which is better then the asp update panel